# pros and cons of site in https?

Tags: .net, security, http, https, owasp

I am looking in to the possibility of creating a new site in full https as oppose to just having parts of it in https eg login. This is based on the guidelines provided in a recent [OWASP report](https://asafaweb.com/OWASP%20Top%2010%20for%20.NET%20developers.pdf)

I am looking for the pros and cons of this approach? Yes I gain security, but what do I lose from do such? All feedback would be great.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cons to full https.

1. The (very slight) performance impact of the encryption
2. The inability to benefit from caching proxies

With modern systems, the performance impact of encryption and session set-up is really a non-issue today.  Performance is no longer an excuse for not using https.

Http proxies can't cache https pages or assets, which can be seen as a good or bad thing.  It's bad if you're depending on caching for performance, and it will mainly affect page assets like scripts, css and images.  Client-side caching should still be effective, though.

These cons are far outweighed by the increased security, authentication and customer confidence provided by full https.

Comment: Thanks for this. What is meant by proxies? I have read that the browser will cache HTTPS same as HTTP.

Comment: @amateur Think proxies you use to connect to the web from behind a corporate firewall. They're allowed to cache content for the whole company to save bandwidth. They obviously can't cache HTTPS content correctly since they don't have access to cache control headers.

Comment: Proxy caching is the main drawback. It means using CDNs and the like is impossible, so images and other purely static context (script libraries, etc.) should still remain http.

Comment: "It means using CDNs and the like is impossible" - could you explain why this may be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Money and Speed.

You need to purchase a security certificate and if you are running subdomains, you would need to invest on a wildcard security certificate (which can be quite expensive).

Your site would be slower on SSL (https) as compared to non-SSL (http).

Comment: From research the performance hit is tiny.

Comment: The performance hit on an individual connection is tiny, but the cumulative effect of a few thousand connections can cause the server's CPU to be heavily loaded (which it usually isn't for simply serving data) as it encrypts all the outgoing data. This can lead to DDoS being easier (as mentioned in another answer) on HTTPS than HTTP. Also note that there are HTTPS hardware accelerator cards available to mitigate this ...

Answer (score 0):

Pros are obvious:
 - connection is secure (which means that confidential and it has integrity)

Neutral:
 - https doesn't provide authenticity (you still need to implement something)
 - all higher levels should be secured too (if connection is secure, it doesn't mean that the whole protocol is secure)

Cons:
 - performance could be slower 
 - as result of slower performance there could be problems with availability (i believe it's easier to DDoS https websites).